# How can we send field in Delete Action which are not Key

Tags: ajax, jquery-jtable

I need to send fields in delete action which are not tagged as Key. As in my Case I want to delete a row using Multiple fields.

Comment: Can you share the code you're working on and the specific problems you're having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer of it. We need to add this code in field section of jtable

```
customDelete: {
    title: '',
    width: '0.3%',
    display: function(data) {
    var $but = $('<button title="delete" class="jtable-command-button jtable-delete-command-button" >delete</button>');
               $but.click(function(){
                   var $dfd = $.Deferred();
                   if(data.record.configType == 'global')
                   {
                       alert('Global Type Configuration are not allowed for deletion.')
                       return false;
                   }
                   if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?')) {
                         $.ajax({
                            url: '/admin/configuration/delete',
                            type: 'POST',
                            dataType: 'json',
                            data: data.record,
                            success: function (data) {
                                $dfd.resolve(data);
                                $('#Container').jtable('load') ;

                            },
                            error: function () {
                                $dfd.reject();
                            }
                        });
                }
            });
            return $but;
        }
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write custom function for delete instead of just URL. And while doin that add the fields you want to send in data to be sent through ajax. Refer the code below as well as documentation http://www.jtable.org/demo/FunctionsAsActions .

```
$('#Container').jtable({
        //...other code
        actions: {
            deleteAction: function (postData) {
                    console.log("deleting from custom function...");
                    //Attach your values to postData... 
                    //make sure you collect it in controller/code
                    postData.customData = $('#myinput').val();
                    return $.Deferred(function ($dfd) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '/Demo/DeleteStudent',
                            type: 'POST',
                            dataType: 'json',
                            data: postData,
                            success: function (data) {
                                $dfd.resolve(data);
                            },
                            error: function () {
                                $dfd.reject();
                            }
                        });
                    });
                },
            //...other actions
        },
    });

    //Load student list from server
    $('#Container').jtable('load');
});
```